# Mysql find value that follows another

Tags: mysql

Hard for me to put in a coherent statement but I can give a sample set

```
ID STATUS DATE
1  A      2016-01-01
2  A      2016-01-01
2  B      2016-01-02
3  C      2016-01-13
4  D      2016-01-14
5  A      2016-01-15
5  B      2016-01-16
6  A      2016-01-17
7  C      2016-01-18
8  B      2016-01-19
9  B      2016-01-20
```

I want an sql statement that can determine two things:
1) How many items go from STATUS = A to a STATUS = B, with the same ID
2) I only want to show the rows with the aforementioned statuses - as follows:

```
ID STATUS DATE        
2  A      2016-01-01
2  B      2016-01-02
5  A      2016-01-15
5  B      2016-01-16

COUNT(distinct ID) of that result should return 2 in this case
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table with itself, matching rows with the row after them with the same id.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.status AS start_status, t1.date AS start_date,
        t2.status AS end_status, t2.date AS end_date
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = date_sub(t2.date, interval 1 day)
WHERE t1.status = 'A' AND t2.status = 'B'
```

This will show both rows together, e.g.

```
id start_status start_date end_status end_date
2  A            2016-01-01 B          2016-01-02
5  A            2016-01-15 B          2016-01-16
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I will give it try tomorrow when I return to work

Comment: Thanks Barmar, that was awesome. I didn't use the date_sub portion, because I plugged this sql into SiSense and, from there, I used a calendar widget to choose the time interval, but regardless, it worked perfect